# How To Overlap Text Over Two Side By Side Images

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and want to have two images side by side with a piece of text in the center of both images.

Html:

```
<div id="body">
    <div class="image-row-container">
        <img class="image-row image-row-1" src="assets/team-photo.JPG">
        <p class="text-overlap" style="position: absolute; left: 25%; transform: translateX(-75%);">The Team</p>
        <img class="image-row image-row-2" src="assets/test.JPG">
        <p class="text-overlap" style="position: absolute; left: 75%; transform: translateX(-25%);">The Vehicle</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-row {
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
height:500px;
}

.image-row-1 {
float:left;
}

.image-row-2 {
float:right;
}
```

So far, I have managed to place the two images side by side and horizontally align the text, but I can't figure out how to simply vertically align the text to the center of the images. If you have any tips of either my primary issue or any recommendations for tips on formatting, different methods, or poor code, it would be greatly appreciated. I am a novice so any help is good help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped each image and text in an additional container, and then absolute positioned the text to be centered on top of the image. I think this is what you were looking for.

```css
.image-row {
  display: flex;
}

.image-container {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-container p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-row">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/500/nature">
    <p>The Team</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/500/nature?t=1529100921702">
    <p>The Team</p>
  </div>
</div>
```